# mysql MONTH date int to full month

Tags: php, html

im sure this is going to be simple but i cant work it out.
Im using the following code to create a tree grid from mysql DB.

```
$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(date) FROM blogs ORDER by YEAR(date) desc")or die(mysql_error());
$archive .= "<ul>";
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql2)){
    foreach ($row2 as $year) { 
    $archive .= "<li class=\"year\" id=\"$year\">$year<ul>";
        $sql3 = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(date) FROM blogs WHERE YEAR(date)='$year' ORDER by MONTH(date) desc")or die(mysql_error());
        while($row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql3)){
            foreach ($row3 as $month) { 
                $archive .= "<li id=\"$month\">$month<ul>";
                $sql4 = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT id,title FROM blogs WHERE MONTH(date)='$month' AND YEAR(date)='$year' ORDER by id desc")or die(mysql_error());
                while($row4 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql4)){
                    $title2 = $row4['title'];
                    $bid = base64_encode($row4['id']);
                    $archive .= "<li><a href=\"../blog/?blogid=$bid\"> $title2 </a></li>";
                }
            } 
            $archive .= "</ul></li>";
        }
    $archive .= "</ul></li>";
    } 
}
$archive .= "</ul>";
echo $archive;
```

It works lovly but the MONTH is echoed out as a int ie 11 how can i convert this into NOVEMBER.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the number to the name by using:

```
$timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 10);
$monthName = date("F", $timestamp);
```

example: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/x1u-5yy

Comment: Excellent thank you new it was something simple :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use also format it directly on your sql.

`select DATE_FORMAT(month,'%M') as month FROM blogs`